# Can't run Start-Process with RunAsUser from .ps1 file

Tags: windows, powershell, script, automation, runas

Wrote a script that copies a .exe file to a folder then tries to run it as another user but the PowerShell window just closes without running the .exe.

The command that runs it works fine if I run it on the terminal but not when I try to run the .ps1 file with PowerShell (the window just closes after copying the file). The command also works (wether I run the .ps1 file or the command on the terminal) if I try to run it as the local user instead of another user.

```
if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste") {
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste" -Recurse -Force | Out-Null
}

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\" -Name "Teste" -ItemType "directory" | Out-Null
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "C:\Users\Gustavo\Downloads\MediaCreationTool22H2.exe" -Destination "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste\" -Description "Backup" -DisplayName "Backup"

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Teste\MediaCreationTool22H2.exe -Verb RunAsUser
```

Comment: It works for you on the console because, PowerShell only runs in the context of the user that started it. New tonight. That's what we're learning and we are joined by two actors who have been in their own right. If you call the console and want to see the process, you must start it that way. See the PowerShell help files on command line execution and leaving that window open. ```powershell /?``` or ```Start-Process``` switches. For example: ```powershell.exe -NoExit``` 'Does not exit after running startup commands', or  ```Start-Process -Wait```

Comment: Also, you can set a scheduled task to run the code as the currently logged-on user or another user for whom you know the credentials. You cannot run GUI tools remotely either, because they require a logged-on user and them running it or an ST running in their context while logged on. Interactive programs mean a user must be there, or that program must have automation switches that you pass  it all it needs, so it can run without user intervention.